# ViewHolder itemView is smaller than expected

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

`ViewHolder` is inflated based on this layout:

[image]

Adding listener to the whole `ViewHolder`, or be exact to `itemView`:

```
userSettingHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
```

But only the first item the `imageView` can active the listener. Why not the whole item, with not last two 'sub'-`recycleview`?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="66dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:padding="0dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rw1"
        android:layout_marginStart="66dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rw2"
        android:layout_marginStart="66dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you add your adapter and the item layout?

Comment: item layout added.

Comment: Seeing your layout, I think you should redefine it. Although, you can have a RecyclerView with a height of 33dp, it is highly recommendable to replace by other views.

Comment: BTW, I see other errors in your layout. One of them is how you position the views inside your RelativeLayout https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html . The other   is that, if you use layout_marginStart, your app will not well displayed in RTL layouts. You should use layout_marginLeft instead. Read this link if you have any doubt about the differences between them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904273/what-is-the-difference-between-android-margin-start-end-and-right-left

Comment: Understood, but you haven't answered my problem.

Comment: Only the first Item; clicking on the image only activate the onclick listener, If yes what do other item do ?

Comment: Requirement is: pressing any of them should trigger listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here when you click on **ImageView** the touch is passed to the parent which will be *itemView*., But when you click on **RecyclerView** it consumes the touch.

I suggest you add this property to both **RecyclerView** in xml

```
android:clickable="false"
```

If this didn't work then you have to subclass the **RecyclerView** and override the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method.

```
public class ScrollThroughRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
public ScrollThroughRecyclerView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ScrollThroughRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ScrollThroughRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return false;
}
}
```

Then in your xml instead of

`<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` use `<your.file.path.ScrollThroughRecyclerView`

But both solutions will make the **RecyclerView** not clickable, and ofcourse not scrollable.

Comment: For a while ~3-5 sec `recycleview` is not able to scroll. Do you know why?