# How can i make my android app look the same on RTL and LTR languages?

Tags: android

When operating on a LTR language phone my app looks fine like this:

[image]

[image]

but when operating on a RTL language phone my app gets either glued to the right like this:

[image]

or you can't even see the screen like this:

[image]

how can i make my app look exactly as it looks on a LTR phone?

p.s i have already tried the refactor adjust to RTL language and it didnt change anything. 
thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow :). While your question seems leggit, it lacks the code so that we can better understand it. Can you post it please? Also, for further questions, please take a look here: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to essentially disable RTL support in your app. To do this, go to your `AndroidManifest.xml` and add this attribute to the `<application>` tag:

```
<application
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    ...>
```

Note that this attribute exists by default, but is set to `true` (so you just need to change the value to `false`).

Comment: Note that the _better_ thing to do would be to support RTL properly, by always using `start`/`end` instead of `left`/`right` throughout your app

Comment: Ben P. - Thanks for the answer, which solves the problem. I think your comment misses something - if supportsRtl is true, then even if you do use start and end, but you only have English, on a device which is set for an RTL language your app won't look right. For example, the activity title will be on the right instead of on the left. Many other things also don't look right.. Using start/end is definitely the right thing to do, but what it gets you is that if you provide language files for RTL languages, your screens will look correct in those languages with no need to tweak the layout.

Answer (score 0):

In your Xml while specifying margins for your views always use the attribute marginStart and marginEnd instead of marginLeft and marginRight.For more info on this refer this answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904273/what-is-the-difference-between-android-margin-start-end-and-right-left)