# What is difference between Android widget position left and start (or right and end) for create Constraint?

Tags: android-layout, android-constraintlayout

For example, if i want to position button B to the right of button A.

[image]

Relative Positioning Constraints:

[image]

I can to use:

1)`<Button android:id="@+id/buttonB" ...
                 app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/buttonA" />`

Or

2)`<Button android:id="@+id/buttonB" ...
                 app:layout_constraintStart_toRightOf="@+id/buttonA" />`

What is difference between example 1 and 2?

References: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no as such difference in both . As you can see in you image , they have mentioned above left as start and right as end .

start and end was introduced in API level 17 [What is the difference between Android margin start/end and right/left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904273/what-is-the-difference-between-android-margin-start-end-and-right-left)

Even if you try to use

```
<Button android:id="@+id/buttonB" ...
             app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buttonA" />
```

will result the same as

```
<Button android:id="@+id/buttonB" ...
             app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/buttonA" />
```

But i didn't find  this constraint till now ... mixture of both start and right. Even this didn't appeared in xml .

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toRightOf
```

Answer (score 1):

> Right/left versus start/end
>
> "Right" and "left" always refer to the right and left sides of the
> screen, whether your app uses a left-to-right (LTR) flow or a
> right-to-left (RTL) flow. "Start" and "end" always refer to the start
> and end of the flow:
>
> For a LTR flow, start = left and end=right. For a RTL flow,
> start=right and end=left. If your app targets API level 17 (Android
> 4.2) or higher:
>
> Use "start" and "end" instead of "left" and "right". For example,
> android:layout_marginLeft should become android:layout_marginStart to
> support RTL languages. If you want your app to work with versions
> lower than Android 4.2; that is, if the app's targetSdkVersion or
> minSdkVersion is 16 or lower:
>
> Add "start" and end" in addition to "left" and "right". For example,
> use both android:paddingLeft and android:paddingStart.

[Source: kotlin-android-training by Google](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-linear-layout#5)