# How is margin start different from margin left and similarly margin end different from margin right in Android xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, layout

So I was using the margins in Android XML and came across the two options which were doing the similar thing. ***Margin start*** and ***margin left*** were doing a similar thing, also ***margin end*** and ***margin right*** were doing same thing.

I was curious to know what is the difference between both of them ? And when should we use what ?

Comment: left is always left, `start` and `end` depends on the device, for left to right, right to left orientations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Android margin start/end and right/left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904273/what-is-the-difference-between-android-margin-start-end-and-right-left)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for different layout direction that is from API 17+:

left to right flow, start=left, end=right.

right to left flow, start=right, end=left.